# Itering array with jquery each

Tags: jquery, arrays, html5-video

I have many video's each under a slider. When a certain video is played and a user has clicked another slider, the prevouis video must stop playing. I've following code that's working correctly.

```
$('#slidername1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#video1').get(0).pause();
})
$('#slidername2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#video2').get(0).pause();
})
```

etc. etc.

Now I want to use an array for the sliders and video's and iterate with e.g. jquery each. I've tried several options, but I didn't manage so far. The slider names are specific names of the video's, so that they are recognized. Anyone a working solution?

Comment: can you share the html sample... ie one slider and video

Comment: I would probably do it a different way : add a class to the video curently being played so that you can trigger it anytime you launch another video,  pause it and remove the class.  This supposes of course you don't have already another way of targetting this video (js variable or any other property you can use)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.each`. Give all the sliders a class, e.g. `class="slider"` and bind to `$(".slider")`.

Then put the ID of the corresponding video in a `data-XXX` attribute.

```
<div id="slidername1" class="slider" data-video="video1">...</div>
```

Then the JS can be:

```
$(".slider").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('video')).get(0).pause();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a single handler for all the sliders, and the index in the slider id and the video id are the same in that case,

One solution could be is to add a common class(like `slidername` - because it is better than using attribute prefix selector for `id`) to all the slider elements

```
$('.slidername').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#video' + this.id.replace('slidername', '')).get(0).pause();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I will check them also. I found a solution myself earlier:

```
var arr = [ "videoname1", "videoname2", "videoname3", "...", "..." ];

jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
   $('#' + val).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('#video' + (i + 1) ).get(0).pause();
});
});
```